# jQueryMobile alternative for windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile

i have a problem, i'm using jquerymobile for some android apps and it runs very nice.

after trying it on windows phone which dont uses the webkit, it relly disapointed me.

when e.g. you click a button its looks very ugly.

do someone know a framework which is quite equal to jquerymobile but optimized for windows phone?

Comment: Do you have an example site? I am running jquery mobile (http://m.kulman.sk/) and I have no problems using it with my windows phone

Comment: yes its running, but the design is not so optimated e.g. when you click a button, you see a canvas arround the button. its not so pretty like on android

Comment: Has it ever occurred to you that your problem is your Windows phone and not jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [jQuery Mobile Metro theme](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/04/introducing-the-jquery-mobile-metro-theme/)? It is, as far as I know, the only HTML5 mobile framework optimised for WP7.